# Unexpected bracket '[' - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I'm writing a small repository for my little app team's Java code, and I have this error all over my code.

```
$base = explode(".", $class)[0];
```

The problem occurs only with this *one* line of code, every time. As far as I know, the above is correct PHP syntax, so what's going on?

**Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in **.../mitc/code/index.php** on line **27**

If you'd like to see the error, it's at http://chancehenrik.x10.mx/mitc/code/ and elsewhere on my site.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's called array dereferencing and [only works in PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)+. You're probably running PHP 5.3.x wherever you are getting that error.

[See results based on different PHP versions](http://3v4l.org/ej1ON)

Comment: I see. The problem was that I was working on two servers, one local and one remote, with local.PHP == 5.4.7 and remote.PHP == 5.3.19.

Comment: See Antony's answer below

Comment: In PHP < 5.4 you need to store the result in a variable first, then dereference it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$exploded = explode(".", $class);
$base = $exploded[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

To work on older versions of PHP (<5.4), you should do:

```
list($base) = explode(".", $class);
```

That is:

```
list($a, $b, $c) = array(1, 2, 3);
```

Now `$a=1`, `$b=2`, and `$c=3`.